# Закрытие всплывающего окна по нажатию кнопки (python kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки во всплывающем окне оно исчезало, а на основном экране добавлялась кнопка. Пытаюсь для закрытия окна использовать dismiss, но он выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dismiss'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.
Код py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

Window.size = (240, 426)

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Content(BoxLayout):

    def new_window(self, *args):
        # создает новую кнопку
        Container.dialog.dismiss()
        self.add_widget(
            Button(text="Новая группа", size_hint_y=None, height=100)
        )

class Container(BoxLayout):
    dialog = None

    def show_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Create new group",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="Done", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_release=Content.new_window
                    )
                ]
            )
        self.dialog.open()

class GrudgetApp(MDApp, Container):
    def build(self):
        self.grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GrudgetApp().run()
```

Код kv:

```
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDCheckbox:
        hint_text: "Online"
        size_hint: (None, None)
        active: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Group name"


<Container>
    Screen:
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.95, 'y': 0.05}
            icon: "icon.png"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            on_release:
                app.show_dialog()

        NavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDToolbar:
                            title: "Navigation Drawer"
                            elevation: 10
                            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                        Widget:

            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer

                ContentNavigationDrawer:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Закрытие диалогового окна размещается в Апп

```
def callback(self, *args):
    self.dialog.dismiss()

def show_dialog(self):
    if not self.dialog:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
             title="Create new group",
             type="custom",
             content_cls=Content(),
             auto_dismiss=False,)
    self.dialog.open()
 
MDTextField:
    id: text1
    hint_text: "Group name"
MDFlatButton:
    id: btn1
    text: "Done"
    text_color: self.theme_cls.primary_color
    on_press: root.create_label()
    on_release: app.callback()

def create_label_пример_функции(self):
     root.ids.tableLayout.clear_widgets()      
     root.ids.tableLayout.add_widget(label)
     label = MDLabel(text=f"{output}", size_hint=(1, None), font_style="Body2", 
                            height="20sp",
                            halign="center", theme_text_color="Custom",
                            text_color=(255 / 255, 172 / 255, 5 / 255, 1))
```

Куда ты и что добавляешь, я так и не понял. Если там у тебя лайаут какой или что еще - присвой ему или вообще всему id и по id сперва очищай (если нужно), а потом добавляй кнопку в этот лайаут.
и почитай про id + о том, чем отличается self, root, app